# jQuery to add _blank to external link

Tags: jquery

I'm making a script which, automatically ads target="_blank" to all external links. 
The problem is that, the script also makes the internal absolute links open in a new tab.
You can check the problem on this test link:
http://www.fairfood.org/testtest/

```
$("a").filter(function () {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).each(function () {
    $(this).attr({
        target: "_blank",
        title: "Visit " + this.href + " (click to open in a new window)"
    });
});
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That page does have some JS errors such as `TWTR is not defined` and `FB is not defined`.  Might want to fix those first.

Comment: `www.fairfood.org` != `fairfood.org`

Comment: I don't believe you need the check the `hostname` here.  also, I believe this object is treated differently in other browsers so simply using the `not` selector w/ your domain name should work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out pixelboy, I am gonna check those errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`www.yourhost.com` is not the same as `yourhost.com`, so when your links don't match, this isn't working.

You can just take out the `www.` if you know that this will always lead to a valid URI.

<sup>(Also, your use of `.each` is *almost* redundant, as jQuery is already knowledgeable about element sets; however, you need it for `this.href`. Just something to be aware of.)</sup>

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return this.hostname &&
           this.hostname.replace(/^www\./, '') !==
              location.hostname.replace(/^www\./, '');
}).each(function() {
   $(this).attr({
       target: "_blank",
       title: "Visit " + this.href + " (click to open in a new window)"
    });
});
```

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/5bWs6/)

Comment: +1 good solution. @Zoltan don't forget to mark it as the answer if it works.  Yeah, I agree, isn't that `each` an unnecessary loop?

Comment: @pixelbobby: See my smaller text. You need it for `this.href`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single jQuery selector to do this:

```
$('a').not('a[href*="fairfood.org/"]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr({target: "_blank", title: "Visit " + 
            $(this).href + " (click to open in a new window)"});
});
```

Comment: thx. added the .org. and +1'd your comment because I laughed when I read it.

Comment: `<a href="http://wow.com/thats-a-very-rare-situation-and-you-have-a-better-chance-of-getting-attacked-by-zombies-which-is-pretty-cool-not-going-to-lie-but-ok-fairfood.org.com.de.us.html" target="_blank">occams razor</a>`

Comment: Also, `this.href` won't work because you took the function scope of `.each` away.

Answer (score 0):

fairfood.org and www.fairfood.org are technically different hostnames. Get rid of www before you test if you want both to work in your script.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, `www.fairfood.org` is not the same host as `fairfood.org`. **Don't treat a WWW and a non-WWW host as one.** Instead, choose whether to use `www` or not; and then *stick with it throughout the site*.

(This has the added benefit of avoiding potential [duplicate content penalties](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html).)

Comment: `<a href="http://lolsomewhereelsethatsnotfairfood.org/hahah.html">Go here!!!1</a>`

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I stand corrected and removed the dodgy solution :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the site at the link you give explains that duplicate content penalties would _not_ be applied in this case.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I confess that I just took the first link I stumbled upon. I may be the case that *Google* does not penalize (and yes, I know that Google ~= internet search), so probably this wasn't the best resource :) However, mixing www and non-www may cause trouble with cookies / cookie based sessions (Unrelated to DCP).

Comment: @jensgram: Yea, it could. I promote writing your website such that *it doesn't matter*, leaving the hostname config to your webserver and keeping it completely abstracted away from your website code. This is largely a matter of personal choice, though.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Agree. And if OP did that, his original code would work (provided that he only used relative links - possible from the root `/...` - within the site).

Comment: @jensgram: Well the relative links worked anyway; it was the absolute ones he was struggling with.